# Arm cortex-M4 crashes with hardfault

Tags: arm, gnu

We get an exception and the lr is **0xFFFFFFF1**. This means that we must cmp msp and psp. The address is now 0x2000E8D0. This is the stackpointer.

Than I get :

```
printf(" - Forced Hard fault.\n")
printf(" - MMAR holds an invalid address.\n");
printf(" - BFAR holds an invalid address.\n");
printf(" - Attempted to execute an instruction that makes illegal use of the EPSR.\n");
printf(" - The processor has attempted to execute an undefined instruction.\n");
```

What can I do now to catch the error further? I interpreted some values around the stack pointer but couldnt find any hint to an error.

The program chrashes after a function which is called from an IRQ.

Comment: You can use normal debug techniques to narrow in on the code causing the fault in a forward direction as well as work backward from the fault.   The lr value just means you are in a handler that also means if you dump the stack you will see a bunch of information, including the address of the instruction or near it that caused the fault.  Read the arm docs to see what exactly is in the stack, should be easy to line it up when you see the dump vs the docs.

Comment: You really have provided no information to help here.  Address of fault disassembly of that area of code and what high level code generated it assuming it is compiled, etc.

Comment: With that info it should be easy to see the bug.

Comment: So easy is it only if all of your code is code. We have a lot of hardware configurations. SPI/UART DMAs. I found it, it was an DMA configuration problem.